# How do I get a mount in Moria?

Tags: lord-of-the-rings-online

How do I get a mount to use in Moria?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As already stated, you can buy a mount from the Iron Garrison Miners if you build enough rep; they have fast mounts that require kindred status, and slower mounts that don't. (Not sure what level of reputation they require.)

There's also an Adventure Pack that comes with a fast goat mount, less hardy than the other mounts but still quite good otherwise -- but I'm not sure if that's still available.

Comment: Kindred and Friend.

Answer (score 7):

3 mounts work in Moria at the moment:

- Iron Garrison Miners goat, available at Kindred reputation level and one at Friend level which goes at 32% speed instead of 62% Kindred reputation level
- LotRO store goat, purchaseable for TP (this one has 60 morale)

Answer (score 3):

You all seem to have forgotten the Thorin's Hall goat, available at Kindred with Thorin's Hall. Thorin's Hall rep items can be earned by killing things in Sarnur. The Thorin's Hall goat has +62% speed and 250 morale, like most rep mounts, which is the same as for the Miners Kindred goat, but this one can be earned before entering Moria. Also, there's the Ale Association goat at Ale Association Kindred (rep can be earned during festivals), and now also the Treasure Laden goat (+68% speed), which is only available as a rare reward during the Treasure Hunt event

Answer (score 2):

According to [this link](http://lotro-chronicles.blogspot.com/2009/04/to-goat-or-not-to-goat.html) you can purchase a goat mount for Moria if you have sufficient standing with the Iron Garrison Miners.

Comment: Hahaha, this made me laugh out loud...A goat!